# django Creating a link for Foreign key in Admin

Tags: django

I am using django1.9,

I have a model that has a foreign e.g

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)

class Bar(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

This is my FooAdmin:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ['bar']

  def def related_bar(self, obj):
    link = urlresolvers.reverse("admin:foo_foos", args=[obj.bar.id])
    return u'<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (link, obj.bar.id)
related_bar.short_description = 'bar'
```

Now in the admin Foo's display list I want to have a link to go to bar display list, i have tried so, but it raises the following error,

```
Reverse for 'foo_foos' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

i am surely missing somethin,but figured it out.So What would be the best way to do that in django? I tried to search in the doc but could not find a relevant howto on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are trying to get `bar` display list but you are resolving `foo_foos` not foo_bar. Also, you are missing `_change` postfix in order to indicate you want admin detail view.

```
def related_bar(self, obj):
    link = urlresolvers.reverse("admin:foo_bar_change", args=[obj.bar.id])
    return u'<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (link, obj.bar.id)
```

From Django docs, admin urls pattern, are these.

```
Page        URL name                                     Parameters
Changelist  {{ app_label }}_{{ model_name }}_changelist  
Add         {{ app_label }}_{{ model_name }}_add     
History     {{ app_label }}_{{ model_name }}_history     object_id
Delete      {{ app_label }}_{{ model_name }}_delete      object_id
Change      {{ app_label }}_{{ model_name }}_change      object_id
```